# When I press enter for a newline in vim, it breaks the indentation of the line

Tags: vim, vi

When I press enter at the end of the "width" line instead of keeping this indentation

```
.header
    width: 100%
```

changes to this

```
.header
  width: 100%
```

I use this configuration in my vimrc. I tried to set noautoindent, but it doesn't solve my problem

```
set autoindent
set noexpandtab
set copyindent
set preserveindent
set softtabstop=0
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
```

Comment: What does `:set sw? ts? sts?` say when editing that buffer?

Comment: @romainl it says `shiftwidth=2`, `tabstop=4` and `softtabstop=0`

Comment: Sorry I forgot the most important part: `:verbose set sw? ts? sts?` This will tell you where that `sw=2` was set.

Comment: What does `:set fo?` say?

Comment: @romainl Thanks I fixed the problem it was caused by a plugin called vim-haml. So I had to change the file that changed the shiftwidth